# Android DownloadManager doesn't change status

Tags: java, android, android-download-manager

for the last few days i'm messing around with DownloadManager in my app.  It kinda works, but have some issues. It downloads file fine, but when I try to open file, it say "Can't open file". Here is download manager code from my app:

```
            Uri source = Uri.parse(url);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    source);

            //Set title and get name file download
            //Replace %20 from filename with spaces
            request.setDescription("Downloading...");
            String split[] = url.split("/");
            String filename1 = split[split.length - 1];
            String filename2 = filename1.replace("%20", " ");
            request.setTitle(filename2);

            //Set path for save download file
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename2);

            //Show notification in notification bar after download
            request.setNotificationVisibility(
                    DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
```

Thath everyone would understand easier, here is some screenshots with the issue:

As you can see, it downloads file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaPVG.png

File is downloaded successfully:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKU0m.png

However, when I enter "Downloads" it still shows, that the file is still in "Downloading..." state. And when I try to open it, it says "Can't Open file"

i.stack.imgur.com/xYvw3.png

i.stack.imgur.com/1mVQn.png

And if I enter Downloads directory with "File Manager", I can see it has been completely downloaded, and If i try to open it, it opens just fine.
Maybe anyone knows how to fix it? or where should I look for an error?

P.S. Sorry if its not so clear, but English isn't my native language.

ArnoldasM